# How to integrate Sass and Play 2.3?

Tags: scala, playframework, sass, playframework-2.3

Is it possible to integrate [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Play Framework 2.3](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Home), so that Sass gets compiled to CSS? If so, how should I go about it? I've tried the [play-sass](https://github.com/jlitola/play-sass) plugin, but it doesn't build with Play 2.3, only up to 2.2.

Comment: Why the votes to close?

Comment: Not sure...writing you an answer now though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, Play has migrated to using [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web) as the model for its asset pipeline, instead of the old system. It's much more flexible than the old system. Unfortunately, since it's so new, it also lacks whole lot of existing packages. You'll either have to write sbt-sass yourself or wait till someone else does. I'm in the same boat for migrating my project to Play 2.3.

From the Play Webinar on Tuesday, Christopher Hunt from Typesafe did a fully fledged example sbt-web plugin for stylus, and linked to the source [here](https://github.com/huntc/sbt-stylus). Most of the logic is written Node-style in a [JS script](https://github.com/huntc/sbt-stylus/blob/master/src/main/resources/stylus-shell.js), with modules pulled from [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) instead of NPM.

The two parts of the process that would have to be modified are in the JS file that  the part for invoking Sass instead of Stylus and the part for parsing errors to pass back to Play. The latter is just editing the `parseError` function. The former you could either do by directly plugging in the code to invoke Sass or by adapting an existing Sass wrapper to WebJar form, as they did with Stylus, and using it in the same way. There are [a couple on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=sass) that might do the trick.

**Edit** I've been using the ShaggyYeti `sbt-sass` package for months now, to great effect. See the other answer.

Comment: Care to comment on the difference between using WebJars versus NPM? I mean, why would I pull in dependencies from that instead of NPM?

Comment: @aknuds1 I think the main win of WebJars is supposed to be that it brings the whole end-to-end process into SBT, rather than having to install node, npm, bower, etc.

Comment: why not use grunt/gulp for compiling sass to css and putting in the same folders as the build script for play does. I plan to do this with my new setup....

Comment: @rizwaniqbal Many people do this. I would argue there are some nice parts aspects of leaning on SBT for your front-end build workflow. Intuitiveness of actually using SBT is not one of them, but it's convenient having just one stack with no external dependencies. Although that's weakened a bit by needing to have Ruby installed to run Sass...

Comment: @acjay, I've had the same issue with installing ruby. Therefore, I [rewrote](https://github.com/irundaia/sbt-sassify) the sbt-sass plugin to use libsass rather than the ruby version. As a result, it shouldn't require any external applications other than SBT. It can be included in SBT by ```addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.0")```

Comment: @irundaia Awesome! Although, I think that if I write another Play Framework application, I'll probably use Scalatags + ScalaCSS.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use my sbt-sass plugin for play framework 2.3.

In future, i'll try to integrate plugin with js compiler. Now it works only with ruby-version of sass.

Link: https://github.com/ShaggyYeti/sbt-sass.

Answer (score 1):

I could install the sass plugin using the following steps:

```
resolvers += "Madoushi sbt-plugins" at "https://dl.bintray.com/madoushi/sbt-plugins/"

addSbtPlugin("org.madoushi.sbt" % "sbt-sass" % "0.9.2")
```

I picked up the latest version from https://dl.bintray.com/madoushi/sbt-plugins/org.madoushi.sbt/sbt-sass/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/

But i got some error during runtime.